# Linear Transformation Surjectiveness

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

If we're given a linear transformation T: U -> V (R<sup>2</sup> -> R<sup>2</sup>) say T(x,y) = (x+y, x-y), how to prove that it is onto?
I tried proving through dimension formula. But I'm not sure if the statement, 'If T is bijective, dimensions of U and V are same' can be applied conversely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick up a point $(u,v)\in V$ and look for a point $(x,y)\in U$ such that $T(x,y)=(u,v)$. It is easy to see that the choice $x=(u+v)/2,\ y=(u-v)/2$ is sufficient (and necessary, too).

Instead of direct calculations, via the dimension formula, you can also argue as follows. First we see $\dim\ker T=0$, hence $\dim T(U)=\dim U-\dim\ker T=2-0=2.$ Therefore, the image $T(U)$ is a 2-dimensional subspace of 2-dimensional space $V$, hence $T(U)=V$.

Comment: So, since (0,0) maps to (0,0) in the function, we have an element in the nullspace {(0,0)}, isn't it? So, isn't the dimension of null space 1? I might be hilariously wrong here because I've learned this just yesterday

Comment: The dimension of $\{(0,0)\}$, that is the dimension of the vector space $W=\{0\}$ is considered as zero, since it contains no linearly independent vector.

Comment: (Note that $1\cdot 0=0$ is a linear dependence relation in $W$.)

Comment: Alrighty, so if it was something like {(2,9), (5,7)} the dimension of null space would be 2 right?

Comment: I get what you want to say, but it is not a linear space...!

Comment: Yeah, didn't realise that. So, just to clarify, is the dimension of null space the number of elements inside the null space of the number of elements inside an element?

Comment: Like in {(1,2,3),(2,4,5)} there are two elements but 1 element itself contains 3 elements

Comment: I don't see. I recommend to look at examples in your textbook carefully.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the solution!